# There has been a critical error on this website. Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress

Tags: wordpress, themes

Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wvs_get_wc_attribute_taxonomy() in /var/www/wp-content/themes/pharmacy2/inc/merlin/includes/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php:329

Comment: Maybe something went wrong while uploading the files and you are missing something or either you should update your theme to see if the problem is fixed. Looks like someone else had your same issue https://pavothemes.com/forums/topic/uncaught-error-on-the-shop-page/

Comment: Error may be related to php version. If you are using php 8 for example, downgrade to an earlier version like php 7.4 or 7.3 .